# exe created using cx_freeze not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

```
 use=input('what do you wanna do \n1.press w to create a new file\n2.press r to read a       file:\n')

 if use=='r':
    read()
 elif use=='w':
    write()
 else :
    print('OOPS! you enter a wrong input\n')
    user()
```

when i run this code using IDLE it runs  properly but when i created a exe of this python file using cx_freeze then the if and elif conditions are not working for 'r' and 'w' respectively. for any input it always goes to the else statement.

I am using python 3.2 and cx_freeze 3.2

Comment: Add `print(repr(use))` after the `input()` so you can see the *actual* contents of `use`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a quick test, I did this:

```
use = input("test input here: ")

for i in use:
    print(ord(i))
```

The result, if you type in "hello", is the ascii character codes for hello, plus "13". This is `\r`, the return character, which is being added to your string. This doesn't happen under Linux and is the result of the fact on Windows a newline is `\r\n` as opposed to just `\n`.

The workaround for you would be to do something like:

```
use = input("test input: ").strip("\r")
```

`strip()` is a string object method that'll remove characters from the end and beginnings of strings.

Notes:

1. The use of `ord()` in the above example is probably not best practise - see Unicode.
2. If you ever write GUIs and use cx_freeze, don't use `print()` or `input()` - on Windows the standard input/output handles don't exist for GUI apps at all. That tripped me up for a while with cx_freeze + gui code. Just a note for when you get there.

Comment: It worked fine using strip(). 
thanks a lot for the valuable Note.