# Python 3: cx_Freeze freezes a working program into a NOT working program

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yes, it looks like it's a duplicate question (already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935043/exe-created-using-cx-freeze-not-working-properly)), however, I have a problem with a Pygame app, not a Console app. It works fine when launching it from IDLE or Python Code Executer (just double-clicking the file :) ), but crashes ***with no tracebacks***. It just keeps crashing (looks like it crashes on the drawing step, I don't know) every time I launch the EXE. The *full* code is here:

```
import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK    = (   0,   0,   0)
WHITE    = ( 255, 255, 255)

# This is a simple class that will help us print to the screen
# It has nothing to do with the joysticks, just outputing the
# information.
class TextPrint:
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)

    def print(self, screen, textString):
        textBitmap = self.font.render(textString, True, BLACK)
        screen.blit(textBitmap, [self.x, self.y])
        self.y += self.line_height

    def reset(self):
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 10
        self.line_height = 15

    def indent(self):
        self.x += 10

    def unindent(self):
        self.x -= 10


pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width,height]
size = [500, 700]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("JoyMonitor V.1.1")
#pygame.display.set_icon("icon.ico")
# Get ready to print
textPrint = TextPrint()

#Loop until the user clicks the close button.
nondone = True

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Initialize the joysticks
pygame.joystick.init()

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while nondone:
    # EVENT PROCESSING STEP
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # User did something
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # If user clicked close
            nondone = False # Flag that we are done so we exit this loop

        # Possible joystick actions: JOYAXISMOTION JOYBALLMOTION JOYBUTTONDOWN JOYBUTTONUP JOYHATMOTION
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONDOWN:
            print("Joystick button pressed.")
        if event.type == pygame.JOYBUTTONUP:
            print("Joystick button released.")


    # DRAWING STEP
    # First, clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    textPrint.reset()
    textPrint.print(screen, "JoyMonitor: Joysticks, Gamepads & Steering Wheels")
    textPrint.print(screen, "Connecting/disconnecting devices requires restart!")
    # Get count of joysticks
    joystick_count = pygame.joystick.get_count()

    textPrint.print(screen, "Number of game input devices: {}".format(joystick_count) )
    textPrint.indent()

    # For each joystick:
    for i in range(joystick_count):
        joystick = pygame.joystick.Joystick(i)
        joystick.init()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Device {}".format(i) )
        textPrint.indent()

        # Get the name from the OS for the controller/joystick
        name = joystick.get_name()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Device name: {}".format(name) )

        # Usually axis run in pairs, up/down for one, and left/right for
        # the other.
        axes = joystick.get_numaxes()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of axes: {}".format(axes) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( axes ):
            axis = joystick.get_axis( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Axis {} value: {:>6.3f}".format(i, axis) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        buttons = joystick.get_numbuttons()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of buttons: {}".format(buttons) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( buttons ):
            button = joystick.get_button( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Button {:>2} value: {}".format(i,button) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        # Hat switch. All or nothing for direction, not like joysticks.
        # Value comes back in an array.
        hats = joystick.get_numhats()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of POVs: {}".format(hats) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( hats ):
            hat = joystick.get_hat( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "POV {} value: {}".format(i, str(hat)) )
        textPrint.unindent()

        balls = joystick.get_numballs()
        textPrint.print(screen, "Number of trackballs: {}".format(balls) )
        textPrint.indent()

        for i in range( balls ):
            ball = joystick.get_ball( i )
            textPrint.print(screen, "Trackball {} value: {}".format(i, str(ball)) )
        textPrint.unindent()
        textPrint.unindent()


    # ALL CODE TO DRAW SHOULD GO ABOVE THIS COMMENT

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
# If you forget this line, the program will 'hang'
# on exit if running from IDLE.
pygame.quit ()
```

Comment: Can you add your `setup.py`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Making an .exe for pygame with cx-freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15735868/making-an-exe-for-pygame-with-cx-freeze), you need to use a system font if you're not going to include the default font of `pygame.font.Font(None,20)`
One solution is to replace:

```
self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, 20)
```

to:

```
self.font = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 20) #or you can use any other system font
```

Or, you can include the ttf file of the default `Font` font in your `setup.py`, which you can get using `pygame.font.get_defaultfont()`